# Is it possible to run linux docker image on windows

Tags: windows, docker, containers

I've built a docker image on my mac and saved it to a tar(client's windows server doesn't have internet access to the outside world so I'll need to transfer this file to them).

From what I understand, on a Windows machine, I can install docker toolbox with VirtualBox, then I can start Docker QuickStartTerminal, which will start a docker machine which is essentially a linux VM.

Then, is it possible to run this docker image on a windows machine, is it specific to certain versions of windows?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: As long as the docker server/engine is running under a Linux kernel, it is always possible to run the Linux docker image under it.

In your case, yes! because docker engine is running under Linux VM under VirtualBox.

Answer (score 8):

It depends what you mean by `running on Windows`, if it is in Windows 7/8/10, or in Windows Server 2016

It is possible with Windows 7/8/10, as it is in fact a Linux VM

It is not possible with Windows Server 2016

You will need a Windows Server 2016 to launch a Windows container, and a Linux server to launch a Linux container.

I will update with a reference

Edit: If you have Windows Server 2016, you can launch an IIS docker container

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/manage_docker

but you can't launch this IIS docker container from a Linux server running docker.

The same applies for a SQL docker container

https://26thcentury.com/2016/01/03/dockerfile-to-create-sql-server-express-windows-container-image/

When you create a Windows docker container, your Dockerfile starts with something like

`FROM windowsservercore`

while when you create a Linux container, your Dockerfile will start with

`FROM debian:jessie`

or

`FROM busybox`

or such

Answer (score 3):

It is now possible to run Linux docker images on Windows 10 natively using Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2).

Steps:

- Install WSL2.
- Install Docker for Windows.
- Go to Docker Settings -> General and check mark "Use the WSL 2 based engine".

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-containers